# Difference between strict separation and strong separation

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have been working through Rockafellar's convex analysis, and seem to be stuck on something which seems rather simple:

In the section on separation theorems,

1. A hyperplane $H$ is said to *strongly separate* convex sets $C_1$ and $C_2$ if there exists some $\varepsilon > 0$ so that $C_1 + \varepsilon B$ and $C_2 + \varepsilon B$ lie in opposite open half spaces associated with $H$, where $B$ is the unit Euclidean ball.
2. A hyperplane $H$ is said to *strictly separate* convex sets $C_1$ and $C_2$, if $C_1$ and $C_2$ lie in opposite open half spaces associated with $H$.

I can't see the difference between the two: if 2 is true, then I can construct open balls around both $C_1$ and $C_2$ so that the open balls are contained in their respective open half spaces. I can then take the minimum of the radii of the two balls, which gives me 1. And I suppose 2 follows trivially from 1.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The balls you construct may have radius $0$ because the sets $C_1$ and $C_2$ could come arbitrarily close to $H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple simple examples in $\Bbb R^2$:

- The half-planes $C_1 = \{(x,y)\mid x< 0\}$ and $C_2 = \{(x,y) \mid x > 0\}$ are convex sets stictly separated by the $y$-axis $x = 0$. But they are not strongly separated, as for any $\epsilon > 0$, for $|x| < \epsilon$, the ball of radius $\epsilon$ about $(x,y)$ will extend over the $y$-axis.

The key here is that the definition of strongly separated requires $\epsilon$ be chosen independently of the point. A single $\epsilon$ must work for every point. But with open convex sets, they can extend right up to the strictly-separating hyperplane.

Closed convex sets are a bit harder to find counter-examples for, but they still exist:

- Define $C_1 = \{(x,y)\mid x < 0, y \ge -\frac 1x\}, C_2 = \{(x,y)\mid x > 0, y \ge \frac 1x\}$. These are closed convex sets that again are stictly separated by the $y$-axis, but they are not strongly separated, as the distance between these sets goes to $0$ as $y$ increases.

However, if $C_1$ and $C_2$ are compact, then the two concepts are the same. If they are are strictly separated, then they will also be strongly separated.